# Can not use html output in PHP with echo

Tags: php, html

I was looking for usage of html in php, and I saw a method that we can use it as like this: `echo '<a href="url">text</a>'`

What I did is this:

```
$redirect = 'Redirecting to login page in 5 seconds. If it does not work, <a href="localhost:51631/login.aspx">click here</a> to do it manually.';
echo 'Account could not be verified. ' . $redirect;
```

When I open the file from localhost, the output looks like this:

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsxo.png)

So far, I've tried pretty much everything, including seperating php tags, putting DOCTYPE html at the top of the file, print function and so on. But in any case, the output looks like this. Any advice? Here is the full code of my php file.

```
<?php

require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';

$db = new DB_Functions();
$token = $_GET["key"];

$redirect = 'Redirecting to login page in 5 seconds. If it does not work, <a href="localhost:51631/login.aspx">click here</a> to do it manually.';

if(isset($_GET["key"]) && $token !== "")
{
    $unique_id = $db->getUniqueIdFromToken($token);
    if(is_null($unique_id))
        echo 'Key not found.' . $redirect;
    else
    {
        $verify = $db->verifyAccount($unique_id);
        if($verify)
            echo 'Account is successfully verified. ' . $redirect;
        else
            echo 'Account could not be verified. ' . $redirect;
    }
}
else
    echo 'Key is missing.' . $redirect;
?>
```

Solution edit: Progman suggested to check the headers, so I applied his suggestion and those come out:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.12' (length=24)
  1 => string 'Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8' (length=43)
string 'BREAK' (length=5)
array (size=1)
  'X-Powered-By' => string 'PHP/5.5.12' (length=10)
```

After I see about the json header, I named it as JSONHeader and removed the header from the original .php file, because the header was also automatically included with "require_once" comment with the file which was distrupting the html output. Thanks @Progman to show me the error.

Comment: `<a href="localhost` is missing `http://` here. If that's all this was, it's off-topic, being a typo.

Comment: What was your question?

Comment: Just tried, didn't work either. My question is about using html tags such as <h3> or <a href="url"> inside a php code. The methods I've tried are explained in the question.

Comment: *what* didn't work?? you trying to redirect automatically?

Comment: *"My question is about using html tags such as <h3>"* - Huh? your question has nothing of that nature. I can't read minds, sorry.

Comment: I'm working on auto redirect, currently it's not the main problem. But the link from <a> tag doesn't seem to work as blue and it's not clickable.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your code; it's clickable. I'm out.

Comment: <?php
$redirect = <<<EOD
<a href="localhost:51631/login.aspx">redirect</a>
EOD;
?>
<?php echo $redirect ?>

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul What is the output of `var_dump(headers_list(), "BREAK", apache_response_headers());`? Please add this code after your `echo` statements and edit your question to include the new debug output.

Comment: @Progman Thanks to you I was able to see what headers are included, removing JSON header fixed the html output. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are sending JSON content type header, the solution is simply setting content-type header as text/html.

here's a fix :

```
<?php 

require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';

$db = new DB_Functions();
$token = $_GET["key"];

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');    

$redirect = 'Redirecting to login page in 5 seconds. If it does not work, <a href="localhost:51631/login.aspx">click here</a> to do it manually.';


if(isset($_GET["key"]) && $token !== "")
{
    $unique_id = $db->getUniqueIdFromToken($token);
    if(is_null($unique_id))
        echo 'Key not found.' . $redirect;
    else
    {
        $verify = $db->verifyAccount($unique_id);
        if($verify)
            echo 'Account is successfully verified. ' . $redirect;
        else
            echo 'Account could not be verified. ' . $redirect;
    }
}
else
    echo 'Key is missing.' . $redirect;
?>
```

Comment: In order to programmers which want to avoid naming the header and removing it from the other file, this solution seems more simple. Since it's working, I marked this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this way, `<a href = "login.aspx">` instead of passing localhost in anchor tag and place your login.aspx file in same directory where this PHP code file is located. Best Luck!